# VLC 'Your Input Can't be Open' Error appeared every time I open a file

Tags: vlc-media-player

Hi my VLC is acting strange. It shows me this window every time I open a video file:

[image]

To be clear, this file was long gone and I am not trying to open this file at all.

What can I do to eliminate this error message? (I can open video files fine but this message is annoying...)

[image]

I don't have anything leftover in my media stream.[image]

Comment: Did you check the various tabs of "Open medium"? Perhaps there is an old entry for this film.

Comment: How do open those video files? Through the finder or throw VLC itself? Try to rename your video file with a shorter name and no space. It looks like file name is somewhat truncated after "Half-".  Can you provide the real full name of this video file?

Comment: @A.Loiseau perhaps I wasn't clear, if I open ANY file through the finder or throw VLC itself, this error message pops up, and no I don't know what the full path of the file name(s) because the file(s) do(es) not exist...I also wasn't trying to open the said file(s).

Comment: @IQV not that I can see. See my new screen shot.

Comment: What about your playlist? Can you see it to ensure it is empty? (you might need menu "View > show sidebar" and check first "playlist" and maybe "library" listings for emptiness).

Comment: @A.Loiseau yes it is, and the same behavior happens on my other mac too. I have to completely remove VLC and reinstall it every time this happens.

Answer (score -2):

looks that it is two years now since the question is asked but i just found the solution to the issue. Go to preferences -> show all-> video -> subtitles -> here you will find the file path that is shown in the error. Remove the file path and save. No more error.